NEXTAUTH / useSession
I am building a web app with Nextjs and I use NextAuth to register and login for Google users and also I use an API to login with a route, but when I log in with Google I get my username and all details, but when I log in with my API route i don't get those details use, I am using useSession to render them.
const {data: session} = useSession()

And I return lets say <h1/>{session.user?.name}<//h1> for both google provider and credentials provider.
Can someone help with a solution?

can you add the API route code to the question

CredentialsProvider({
name: 'Credentials',
credentials: {
username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
},
authorize: async (credentials) => {
if (!credentials) return null;
    const res = await fetch('https://route-here', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
      }),
    });


const user = await res.json();
    if (res.ok && user) {
      return {
        name: user.name,
      };
    }

    return null;
  },
}),

then i returned the user

You need to add the session callback to get the logged users details in the client component which you use useSession()
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        if (!credentials) return null;

        const res = await fetch('route-here', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  }
});


Then get the user details like this
'use client';

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const UserProfile = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  if (status === 'loading') return <p>Loading...</p>;

  if (!session) return <p>You are not logged in.</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome, {session.user?.username}!</h1>
      <p>Email: {session.user?.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;

